Profile picture missing on Super User
Just noticed this around 10:40pm (EST), but it seems like the small profile pic that shows the menu bar as well as question and answer context seems to be broken. Seems fine on *.stackexchange.com sites.
Missing profile picture in the menu bar:



Missing profile picture in the question and answer context:




Can confirm its broken for me too - The image should be https://i.sstatic.net/M97cU.jpg?s=256 which is broken. "view image" gives me this adorable error https://i.sstatic.net/UD80U5WE.png for this link. Might potentially be a migration issue from the 'old' imgur ava hosting to the new ones?

Seems broken on my profile too https://superuser.com/users/10165/journeyman-geek https://i.sstatic.net/Um5vXmxE.png

A note to potential close voters: issues related to the image migration from Imgur to SE internal are explicitly on-topic for this site, even if a given problem may only manifest on a single site.

I think  avas got migrated on SU first. The other sites I looked at that work have the 'old' i.imgur avas

Appears to be fine now. Still broken for some?

can repro that his avas, and the ones of mine that were broken work now.

I will accept 100% responsibility for this one, acting on my own and inadvertently skirting the boundaries of the well-organized project to transition from Imgur to our own service.
TL;DR
As part of testing the rollout of URL changes across the network, I jumped the gun and updated profile picture URLs for a subset of users in Blender and Super User. This wouldn't have been a problem technically, except that we performed a full refresh of the migrated images last night, during which each affected user's profile picture would return a 404 for some portion of the copy operation.
Background
If you want the longer story, try and count the perfect storm of mistakes I made here.
As you may recall from previous broad, sweeping URL fix-'em-ups, there is a lot of meticulous work involved in replacing URLs, particularly in post bodies. It is even harder to undo these operations if you were so confident going in that an undo couldn't possibly be necessary, and also if you were intentionally trying to leave no trace:

We don't want to explicitly modify the post, otherwise we'll cause chaos on the front page for every post we bump (and other side effects).
We need to modify post history content as well, so that updates aren't inadvertently reverted through rollbacks, and so that side-by-side continues to render pictures correctly even if an old image URL stops resolving.

When you update posts "quietly," there isn't an easy revision to roll back to - that's called restoring a database backup.
In this case specifically, we need to modify all valid imgur.com image links to point to sstatic.net instead. This is made possible because - and I'm simplifying here - we copied all of our assets from imgur.com to a new location under sstatic.net (let's call this the "legacy bucket").
With all that in mind, I spent a lot of time testing my scripts in isolated environments. Not just updating posts - the most difficult part - but also updating other minor places, like profile pictures.
But I made bad assumptions about the rollout; I assumed that, after a site was fully operational with the new uploader, that it would be safe to update any URLs because they were already migrated to the legacy bucket. In my head, this meant to me that it was okay to start testing scripts and actually moving URLs to the new domain. Clearly, I was wrong about that.
This was several days ago, before I knew we were planning to provide "some advance warning" before touching any data. So, I did some dry runs against two of the sites in the first wave of the uploader change: Blender (a smaller, quieter site, where iterations could be quick) and Super User (a larger, busier site, where we'd get a more realistic feel for both duration against larger tables and contention with normal site operation). I did this for post bodies, profile pics, and a few other minor places; then tested that all of the changes looked good and that known false positives were ignored.
Fast forward a couple of days, when someone told me we were planning to take the legacy bucket offline and refresh it (let's call this the "legacy refresh"). It involved deleting all of the migrated images in the legacy bucket and transferring them again.
After, ahem, changing my pants, I set to work on the undo script for posts that I was previously confident I would never need. Because I immediately realized that all the posts I changed would have broken images during the legacy refresh, which would severely diminish their utility.1
This was somewhat of a panic on my part because the "quiet" touch combined with being over-confident and believing it was a one-time, one-direction change required an even more careful revert.
I prioritized posts because - again, in my head - most everything else that might show a broken image temporarily is not great, but still largely cosmetic. And I had hope that, if and when we did perform the legacy refresh, it would be off-hours, when few if any would notice the remainder, including profile pictures. This was a calculated risk vs. the effort of changing those other places back - only to have to change them back again a third time. I shouldn't have been lazy. Clearly, I was wrong about that, too.
1 At least for the posts that have images for the right reasons.
Therefore
That is why some of you observed temporarily missing profile pictures during last night's legacy refresh - the URLs were pointing at sstatic.net, but the images weren't there anymore. Some were missing longer than others, depending on the first character in your profile image's filename, as they were moved in large batches but in somewhat alphanumeric order.
Was this my best work or my proudest moment? Absolutely not! I apologize for the assumptions and decisions I made that led to a brief period of missing profile images.
Next
I can assure you the remainder of the rollout will be a much more formalized plan with milestones, contingencies, and someone looking over my shoulder for my part.
You will get more details about those plans soon.

Don't worry, there are 28,894,033 users looking over your shoulder ...

To be honest, I prefer going ahead without formal plan and then quickly fixing any mistakes, over strictly staying within a formal plan, then fixing after much longer time without saying anything. So kudos, mistakes happen, and it's all good.

So long term, there is an intention to release   i.stack.imgur.com  ?
